# Graph API for OneDrive returns item not found

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

I am seeing that for an item the metadata query (GET /drives/drive-id/items/item-id) is failing with response Code: 404 "The resource could not be found".

What we have seen that this particular item is marked with red circle in OneDrive (we haven't made any changes to enable any such policy). And the following policy tip is present for this item "This item is protected by a policy in your organisation. Access to this item is blocked for everyone except its owner, last modifier, and the site owner."

I am using OAuth token to access the item and the token has all relevant permission by Global Admin. I can download other items metadata but it fails only for this particular item.

Has anyone seen this kind of behavior? Please let me know.

Comment: Is it OneDrive of specific user? Your endpoint is not correct. It should be GET /drives/{drive_id}/items/{item_id}.

Comment: Sorry. somehow the url got stripped. I am using /drives/<driveID>/items/<itemsID> url.